# How to create a permanent shortcut to files on windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, shortcuts

I recently installed (with help!) an ubuntu partition on my computer while keeping a windows partition. I would like to create a permanent shortcut to quickly access files on the windows partition and not to go through all folders (OS, users and so on) each time. I can create a shortcut but it ceases to work each time that I start my computer. 
So my question is: how to create a shortcut which is permanent so that I can quickly acces my windows files? 
Thanks in advance to help me begin with this amazing adventure which is Linux! :p
Guigeek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automount the Windows partition to a specified mount point by editing `/etc/fstab`. This mount point has to be created before editing `/etc/fstab`. Create it using

```
sudo mkdir <mount_point>
```

- `<mount_point>` is usually a directory inside `/media`. I use `/media/Data` as my `<mount_point>`. You may want to use `/media/OS` (instead of Data and OS you can use any name you wish).

Then, you need to get your partition's UUID and type. To do that, run

```
sudo blkid
```

After determining which is your desired partition, edit `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

At the end of the file add the following (since you are using Windows, I suppose that your partition's type is NTFS):

```
UUID=<your_partition's_UUID> <mount_point> ntfs-3g  defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dmask=007,uid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

- `<your_partition's_UUID>` is the UUID you got from `blkid`.
- `<mount_point>` is the mount point you created before, e.g. `/media/OS`.
- `ntfs-3g` is your partition's file system type (I supposed NTFS; if it is of another type it must be specified accordingly).
- the rest of the options set the permissions on the partition. The ones I used above give you permission to read and write to your partition and also remove the executable permission from all files of it.

Save your changes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, close nano using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

The above settings work really well for me. However, if you need something different or you need more details about `fstab`, check this [fstab wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

After this procedure, your shortcuts may not work at first. After recreating them they should work properly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97596/discussion-on-answer-by-user3140225-how-to-create-a-permanent-shortcut-to-files).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to auto mount your Windows drives. Please note that you need to auto mount only those drives whose files you have added as shortcuts to Nautilus. See this related article: https://csetutorials.com/auto-mount-ntfs-partitions-startup-ubuntu-linux.html
2. Add the folder location as a *Favourite* through Nautilus (Files) using *Bookmark this location*. It will appear on the left-hand side of Files, just like as you can see in the screenshot below the `/` folder I have added as a Bookmark.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I can't have it work properly. When I try to save the text editor /etc/rc.local, I get this message in the terminal: ** (gedit:2891): WARNING **: 19:52:41.435: Set document metadata failed: La définition de l’attribut metadata::gedit-position n’est pas prise en charge (sorry for the french, last sentence means sth like: definition of the metadata::gedit-position attribute isn't covered). Any idea? One (possibly stupid) question: a drive = a partition?