# How to open a shortcut to a folder on windows partition without having to enter password?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, shortcut-keys, password

This question follows a previous question of mine [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166589/how-to-create-a-permanent-shortcut-to-files-on-windows-partition/1166615?noredirect=1#comment1945970_1166615).

A user helped me to create a permanent shortcut to a folder located on the windows partition. I now can access this folder directly thanks to the shortcut but my password is asked twice when I click on it at the beginning of each session, which makes the shortcut a little less short! Actually to access any file or folder on the windows partition, I need to type my password twice.

I would like not to have to enter my password at all to access this folder through the shortcut. How can I do it? 
Before the actions to get a permanent shortcut, I wasn't asked my password. These actions were primarily to create a mount point by editing /etc/fstab and then to try to change the ownership of the partition but it didn't work (more details on the other question). 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: complete `/etc/fstab` is:

```
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=bd39de4c-2aa3-4126-959f-b73b968d92db /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A41F-68E2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=90EA2482EA2466A6 /media/guigeek/OS ntfs-3g  defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dmask=007 uid=1000,windows-names 0 0`
```

Comment: Please post your relevant /etc/fstab entry.

Comment: You mean this: UUID=90EA2482EA2466A6 /media/guigeek/OS ntfs-3g  defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dm117,dmask=007 uid=1000,windows-names 0 0 ? I'm a complete newbie in Linux, so I lack much knowledge about what is what.

Comment: OK - what does `mount | grep /media/guigeek/OS` show?

Comment: BTW, your `/etc/fstab` entry should be like this: ` UUID=90EA2482EA2466A6 /media/guigeek/OS ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dm117,dmask=007,uid=1000,windows-names 0 0

Comment: It shows: `/dev/sda3 on /media/guigeek/OS type fuseblk (ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
`. About the /etc/fstab entrey, you meant that I should write it differently in the comment write? Like with ` `?

Comment: Not sure why it's mounting read-only...what does `ls -l /media/guigeek` show? Are you dual-booting with Windows 10? If so, is Fast Boot enabled?

Comment: It shows `total 16
drwxrwx--- 1 root root 16384 août  19 20:17 OS`. I'm dual booting with Windows 10 and I just checked: fast boot is enabled. Should I turn if off?

Comment: Yes, turn off Fast Boot. Reboot into Linux, then unmount the partition (`sudo umount /media/guigeek/OS`). Then, change the ownership of `/media/guigeek/OS` to your user/group ID (`sudo chown your_username /media/guigeek/OS`). Remount the partition (`sudo mount /media/guigeek/OS`).

Comment: I turned off the Fast Boot and did as you wrote but there is an issue when I want to remount partition. Namely, I get this message: `mount: /etc/fstab : erreur d'analyse à la ligne 13 — ignorée
mount: /media/guigeek/OS : impossible à trouver dans /etc/fstab.` It means that there is an issue with line 13 (which is the `/etc/fstab` entry I added myself) and then that `/media/guigeek/OS` cannot be found in `/etc/fstab`). I then just restarted the computer but I'm still asked my password twice to get either to the shortcut or to the windows partition files in general.

Comment: OK - post your entire `/etc/fstab` (add it to your question, not here).

Comment: Delete the last (2) lines and and this (MUST be on one line): `UUID=90EA2482EA2466A6 /media/guigeek/OS ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dm117,dmask=007,uid=1000,windows-names 0 0`

Comment: It's working perfectly fine now! Thanks a lot for your patience and for your help!

Answer (score 2):

create a credential file like:

```
username=user
password=password
```

Let's say under /root/.ntfspass
Put in this in your fstab file

```
UUID=90EA2482EA2466A6 /media/guigeek/OS ntfs-3g credentials=/root/.ntfspass,defaults,nls=utf8,fmask=117,dmask=007 uid=1000,windows-names 0 0
```